# Finding a filename then printing the path/filename plus specific lines in the file to an output file

Tags: file, path, filenames, lines

I'm close to solving this one but I seem to have hit a wall. I want to search for filenames, grab the contents of lines 14 to 17, then print to an output file the /path/filename and then the contents of lines 14 to 17, concatenated to the same line, separated by spaces.

So in a directory containing:

```
/path1/filenameX.txt
line 14: 3
line 15: 4
line 16: 9
line 17: 5
```

and

```
/path2/filenameY.txt
line 14: 56
line 15: 10
line 16: 70
line 17: 89
```

I would want the output file to read as follows:

```
./path1/filenameX.txt 3 4 9 5
./path2/filenameY.txt 56 10 70 89
```

I've been searching a lot for the solution to this problem, and by now (largely thanks to this site!) I have individual pieces of it solved but getting them all to work together is proving extremely difficult.

Here's an example of one of the solutions that didn't quite work:

```
find . -name 'filename*' -print0 -exec cat {} \; | head -n 17 | tail -n 4 | tr '\n' ' ' > output.txt
```

While other attempts were getting the filname included in the output file but not the contents of the lines, this one above got the contents of the lines in, but not the filename, also this latest one only read one file.

Any combination of sed, grep, awk, cat or whatever else will work on the command line is a-ok, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
root@dell:/tmp# find . -name 'filename*' | while IFS= read -r line; do  echo -n "$line "; sed -nre '14,17p' $line | tr '\n' ' '; echo   ; done
./path1/filenameX.txt 3 4 9 5 
./path2/filenameY.txt 56 10 70 89
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Initially that gave me "sed: illegal option -- r". So instead of "sed -nre" I just put "sed -ne" and it worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for each example separately

```
 awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s ", "."ARGV[1]} NR <=17 && NR >=14 {printf "%s",$3 } END{print x}' /path1/filenameX.txt`
```

And with the while loop by Tiago

```
find . -name 'filename*' | while IFS= read -r line ; do  awk 'BEGIN{printf "%s\t", ARGV[1]} NR <=17 && NR >=14 {printf "%s ", $3 } END{print x}' $line ; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I do need to search the directory for files matching 'filename*' using the script rather than running a separate script for each of files separately, primarily because there are hundreds of the files within the directory and subdirectories.

Comment: Oh I see...Well you can use Tiago's while loop with the awk one liner above. I've modified the answer.